# Flutter Web : javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to add firebase to my flutter web app, i keep getting this error and i dont know why anymore, i have tried everything

Google chrome console error

```
3(index):1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
zone.dart:1175 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at Object.X1 (core.dart:54)
    at cloud_firestore_web.dart:36
    at Qi.a (async_patch.dart:315)
    at Qi.$2 (async_patch.dart:340)
    at Object.an (async_patch.dart:245)
    at Object.BB (main.dart:8)
    at js_helper.dart:2677
    at js_helper.dart:2677
    at dartProgram (js_helper.dart:2677)
    at js_helper.dart:2677
```

here is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="weepay_web">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>weepay_web</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
       https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
 
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyBqi_VL9n1FGXfK2LifaQjVGIm4XN3Sdkw",
        authDomain: "wepay-c6dad.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://wepay-c6dad.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "wepay-c6dad",
        storageBucket: "wepay-c6dad.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "10570764732",
        appId: "1:10570764732:web:0f56355e304272af91dbb9",
        measurementId: "G-539E2WLH93"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
  
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?v=3346340368');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js?v=3346340368" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my pubspec yaml file

```
name: weepay_web
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
 
  


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_core_web: ^0.2.1

  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

and here is my main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './pay_link.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
            initialRoute: "/home",

            routes: {
        "/home": (context) => Container(color:Colors.orange)
       
      },onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          List<String> pathComponents = settings.name.split('/');
          if (pathComponents[1] == 'link') {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return PayLinkScreen(payment_link:pathComponents.last);
              },
            );
          } else
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return Container(color:Colors.orange);
              },
            );
          
        },

      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // This makes the visual density adapt to the platform that you run
        // the app on. For desktop platforms, the controls will be smaller and
        // closer together (more dense) than on mobile platforms.
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

...................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love to help you but could you share the error you get in the Chrome console log?

Usually, the problem is that you are using firestore and others but did not include them in the index.html.

For example:

```
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
           https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

If you share more information on your error I could try to help you better but this is my first assumption.

More info you can find on https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

---

After your additional info, I looked closer at your code and it seems that you do not add the scripts in the proper order.

Please look at my standard Flutter Web App index.html:

```
<body>

  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
       https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>



  <script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxx-id",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    appId: "1:XXXXXXXX:web:XXXXXXXXXX",
    measurementId: "G-XXXXXXXXXXX"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
 <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

So all the scripts are in the body not the head.

Comment: Changed the answer. Hopes it helps, also mark your API key in your question.